# Bit data type size when it is NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bit, sqldatatypes

The bit data type in SQL Server is the smallest data type, it is just a single bit with a value of 0 or 1.

If the field been updated with 0 value then in that field spot in the hard-disk a 0 will be stored, if field updated with 1 then 1 will be stored in the hard-drive.

What does it store when it is NULL?

Comment: You are focusing on how the *value* of the field is stored. If the field is nullable, it must also store a bit saying *whether* there is a value or not in that field.

Comment: @Tanner I am talking about that 1% of the cases

Comment: @Tanner yes, it does :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null state of a column is stored separately from the data - each data row has a section called the NULL BITMAP which has one bit for every column in the table (whether it is nullable or not) that holds the null/not null state of the column. So a bit column actually takes two bits - one for the null state, one for the data.

Just FYI, the data space a bit takes in SQL server is variable - it depends on how many bit columns you have. It can store up to eight bit columns in a byte, so if you have only one bit column you're still using a whole byte for the row (the other seven bits are ignored).